# How to add external libraries to my C++ project with Cmakelists?

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I'm new to C++ so be gentle with me. (I know how to code but I get complicated with all the build/compile stuff)

I am using Clion with my C++ project and I have difficult to understand how to include external libraries that I download from the Internet.

for example I have downloaded the OpenCV library (and It located on /usr/local/Cellar/opencv , I cant tell why) and all I have to do in my CmakeLists is to add

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(ArucoMarkersCpp ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

this is my full CmakeLists right now:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(ArucoMarkersCpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(ArucoMarkersCpp main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(ArucoMarkersCpp ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

I want to include to my project the [this library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/aruco/files/). In all the tutorials I have found, all the examples libraries have inside their main folder, an "include folder" and more. but in this library it seems that it doesn't have it.

The library folder that I downloaded from the link:
[image]

I want a General way to do it, without rely on Clion or any other IDE. I want to do it with makefile/Cmakelists (I don't really understand the difference)

Where do people usually put their libraries' files and how they import/include it to their project?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you compile ArUco library and install it ?